# css cursor:pointer won't work with js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a simple tabs module using bootstrap. Here is my code

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs subentry-nav" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab"><h4>Red</h4></a></li>
    <li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab"><h4>Orange</h4></a></li>
    <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab"><h4>Yellow</h4></a></li>
    <li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab"><h4>Green</h4></a></li>
</ul>
```

I declared a css style to make the cursor pointer on it.

```
.subentry-nav.nav>li {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

It looks fine at this stage.

Then I tried to make the tab switch on hover instead of on click, so I added this piece of js function:

```
$('.nav-tabs > li').hover(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('hoverblock'))
        return;
    else
        $(this).find('a').tab('show');
})

$('.nav-tabs > li').find('a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('hoverblock');
})
```

After adding this piece of code, the cursor attribute won't work anymore. Any idea where I did wrong?

Comment: Unrelated bug: `$('nav-tabs > li')` should be `$('.nav-tabs > li')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It get's overriden by other bootstrap classes which have:

```
.nav-tabs>.active>a, .nav-tabs>.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>.active>a:focus{
    cursor:default;    
}
```

One solution whould be to change

```
.subentry-nav.nav>li {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

with

```
.nav-tabs>.active>a, .nav-tabs>.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>.active>a:focus{
    cursor:pointer;    
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: @alvinzoo if your problem is solved, you have to accept the answer.